# Google's v8 engine with C++11

Tags: c++, node.js, c++11, v8, embedded-v8

Can v8 (Google's open source JavaScript engine) be used with C++11?

Comment: Read the question you just asked, out loud.

Comment: My english is not great. If you edited it with correct English I will consider it a favor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/v8/embed

> The V8 API provides functions for compiling and executing scripts,
>   accessing C++ methods and data structures, handling errors, and
>   enabling security checks. Your application can use V8 just like any
>   other C++ library. Your C++ code accesses V8 through the V8 API by
>   including the header include/v8.h.

It´s a sublink of the one you commented, i hope it helps.

Comment: i assume that the version number should not be a problem in that case

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as of today it can be used effectively with C++11, and even C++14 semantics. I had this same question while writing a [v8 project](http://github.com/cosmicexplorer/native-mutex), which uses a multitude of C++11 (and later) threading features.